# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') - Sequelize with oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

I was trying to connect and get data from oracle database using sequelize, but it was returning an error  **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'): undefined**

Here is the code :

**Connection**

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import _projects from "../models/projects.js";

export const getProjects = async (req, res, next) => {
var conn = new Sequelize({
            dialect: 'oracle',
            username: dbAdmin,
            password: dbPass,
            dialectOptions: { connectString: connStr } // also tried { connectionString: connStr }
        });

        function initModel(connection) {
            const projects = _projects.init(connection, DataTypes);
            return { projects };
        }

        var db = initModel(conn);
        const all_projects = await db.projects.findAll()
        console.log("all_projects", all_projects.rows); // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'): undefined
}
```

**projects.js**

```js
import _sequelize from 'sequelize';
const { Model, Sequelize } = _sequelize;

export default class projects extends Model {
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init({
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                allowNull: false,   
                primaryKey: true
            },
            credat: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: true,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('getdate')
            },
            description: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(1024),
                allowNull: true
            },
            picture: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                allowNull: true
            },
            settings: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: true
            },
            is_deleted: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: true
            }
        }, {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'projects',
            schema: 'dbo',
            timestamps: false,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you confused `findAll` with `findAndCountAll` which returns `rowa` and `count` and also you didn't indicate any parameters at all (which can lead to this error with `undefined`) in `findAll`:

Compare:

```js
 const all_projects = await db.projects.findAll({})
 console.log("all_projects", all_projects);
```

and

```js
 const a_page_of_projects = await db.projects.findAndCountAll({
   limit: 10,
   offset: 0
 })
 console.log("a_page_of_projects rows", a_page_of_projects.rows);
 console.log("a_page_of_projects count", a_page_of_projects.count);
```